# Read a file and pipe to grep

Tags: linux, grep

Wondering if anyone can help me, I'm very rusty with bash and seem to hit a bit of an impasse.

I'm storing a list of strings in a file and would like to read the file and pipe each line returned to grep which in turn searches a directory for files containing the string.

Initial attempt:

```
cat filename | grep -lr *
```

However this is not returning any output.

Can anyone give me some directions on the best approach?

Answer (score 4):

[Avoid that useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org./era/unix/award.html#cat).  You can of course solve this with `xargs` and the like.  But that's over-complex compared to a simple `while` loop.

```
while read i 
do
    grep -r -- "$i" directory/
done < filename
```

Comment: Are you sure about that peth? Pretty sure it finishes after the last line of `filename`.

Comment: Ah apologies, never saw the sneaky edit. Never used the pipe up there before either..

Comment: You also have to check the end of line character used in your file. It should be `\n` (line feed) and not `\r` (carriage return).

Answer (score 2):

I would try this.

```
cat filename | while read line ; do grep -lr "$line" * ; done
```

You could also pipe it to "sort -u" so you don't get duplicate.